# How do you make awk ignore special characters in the input file?

Tags: unix, awk, special-characters

Ok, So here is the issue. I am trying to create an awk program that adds a few characters to a column in a file. Simple enough, but the problem is the file contains characters awk interprets as escape or special characters, such as \ ^ & and /... I want awk to act as if all characters in between the field separator (or any non field or new record character actually)  are simply supposed to be there and don't convey special informatoin. i don't want it to interpret any of the file in any special way. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This question does not make sense to me. awk does not interpret the chars inside the processing file. Could you post an example of your file and the awk command you have tried to apply to it?

Comment: awk -f NH3 'BEGIN { FS = "|" ; print $2 }'

Comment: and the output is : awk: NH3:1: 06/13/2012 10:24:44|his_in2|06132012|CL71174588|MSH|^~\&|HBOC|A|PCM|                                                                             PID||EPN23433333^^^A^EN|MRN23433333^^^A^MR||TESTNIC^MEDS1|SUPERTEST|19800613|M||                                                                             PV1||I|MEDICAL^^|||^^|8015|||MED||||8|||8015|I/P||80|||||||||||||||||||A|OCC||||                                                                             20120613102440
awk: NH3:1:              ^ syntax error

Comment: AND : awk: NH3:1: 06/13/2012 10:24:44|his_in2|06132012|CL71174588|MSH|^~\&|HBOC|A|PCM|                                                                             PID||EPN23433333^^^A^EN|MRN23433333^^^A^MR||TESTNIC^MEDS1|SUPERTEST|19800613|M||                                                                             PV1||I|MEDICAL^^|||^^|8015|||MED||||8|||8015|I/P||80|||||||||||||||||||A|OCC||||                                                                             20120613102440
awk: NH3:1: ^ backslash not last character on line

Comment: just printing out the 2nd column as a test, the end program will actually print all columns out, manipulating 3 of the columns.

Comment: Using `-f` tells awk that the file `NHS` contains an awk program.  If you want `NHS` to be input data, just specify `NHS` as an argument after you give the program.

Comment: NM I think I figured it out. -f is for a awk program file, not an input file. the input file is put on the awk line after the program. Thanks will! I think I was typing my message as you posted yours. Yes that is the problem. fundamental misunderstanding of the awk syntax.

Comment: I believe @WilliamPursell got it. However, just to be sure, could you post an example of the _input file_, as well an example of the _output result_, by editing the question? It is rather difficult to read it in comments.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. fundamental misunderstanding of the awk syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your comments, it seems that you are telling awk to use the file as if it were a program rather than treating it as data. Try:

```
awk -F\| '{print $2}' NH3
```